# Use regular expression to match a subtring of a pattern in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to query all strings that match the following pattern in mysql.

1. At least one non-empty character,
2. followed by a literal dash character `-`,
3. then followed by at least one non-empty character,
4. then followed by the literal string `in ('true')`

the substring of "`and`" can not appear in between `-` and `in ('true')`.

For Example:

```
segment-123 in ('true')
```

matches the above pattern.

```
content-foo and segment in ('true')
```

does not match the above pattern because it has the substring "`and`" in between `-` and `in ('true')`.

Is this achievable using REGEXP in mysql? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> select 'segment-123 in (\'true\')'
    regexp '[^[:space:]]+-[^[:space:]]+ in \\(\'true\'\\)' as matched;
+---------+
| matched |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+

mysql> select 'content-foo and segment in (\'true\')' 
    regexp '[^[:space:]]+-[^[:space:]]+ in \\(\'true\'\\)' as matched;
+---------+
| matched |
+---------+
|       0 |
+---------+
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax for more documentation on the regular expression syntax in MySQL.